# Comparing data in same table SQL

Tags: sql, sybase

Table: working_history

```
ID     Field     Event_dt      Data
145    Reason    10/20/2003     DOM
145    Reason    9/20/2007      LVE
145    Reason    3/17/2008      RTN
145    Reason    4/5/2008       POP
145    Reason    3/7/2009       POP
145    Reason    6/13/2009      TRE
145    status    10/20/2003     A        
145    status    6/5/2006       L        
145    status    11/27/2006     A        
145    status    9/20/2007      L        
145    status    3/17/2008      A        
145    status    6/12/2009      T
```

I want anyone who had an ESTA=L, and then check to make sure that their respective Reason event_dt match Status event_dt. In the above table,

```
145    status    6/5/2006       L
```

should come back, as event_dt (6/5/2006) for field.status = L, does not have a data where Field = reason on the same date.

Comment: In the future post what you've tried as well.  It will help us help you.

Comment: What is `ESTA`? Is it the same as `Data`?  I'm not clear what kind of output you are expecting.  Can you provide full result set based on your sample data?

Comment: ESTA is Status, so Field  ='Status' and Data = 'L'. 

sample result
145    status    6/5/2006       L (as there is no Event_dt where Field = 'Reason' for this record).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM working_History WHReason
RIGHT JOIN Working_history WHStatus
  on WHReason.ID = WHStatus.ID 
  and WHReason.field = 'Reason' 
  and WHStatus.field = 'status' and WHStatus.Data='L'
  and WHReason.Event_DT = WHStatus.Event_DT
WHERE WHReason.Event_Date is null
```

Assuming you're only looking for status's that do NOT have a reason and not the other way.

This basically says, create two sets of information one for fields of reason one for fields of status.  Then combine those two results based on their ID and event date including all records from the status set and only those that match in reason.  Limit that result to only include those that have no reason event date.

It uses a concept called a Self Join to generate two sets of data allowing one to quickly identify information in one set but not the other.  [Visual reference](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thanks xQbert. The SQL you mentioned gives me for all Data (where Field = 'Status'). i wanted to find all ids whose Event_DT with Field = 'Status' and Data ='L', is (Event_DT) not available where Field = 'Reason'.
for example, in the above table, "145    status    6/5/2006       L", has no EFDT with Field = 'Reason'

Comment: @KU added `and WHSStatus.Data = 'L'`